# Problems that occur when dragging and dropping controls using the designer made by IDesignerHost

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a designer generated using IDesignerHost, and I have bound the toolbox and property bar to it. When I drag and drop a Button or CheckBox control to the Form in the designer, the control is always generated at the position where my mouse is released. This is This is a normal phenomenon, but when I drag and drop the Panel or TabControl controls, they are always generated in the upper left corner of the designer Form control. Does anyone have the same experience?There is another problem. When I drag and drop a TextBox on the design panel, all the controls on the interface will not respond until you drag and drop another control.

When dragging and dropping container controls such as Panel and TabControl, the controls are generated in the correct position of the designer, and the problem of the entire design interface becoming unresponsive after dragging and dropping TextBox is solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.